# Weblogic startup and ear deployment take too long

Tags: deployment, ear, java-ee-7, weblogic14c

I am working on a Javaee project using weblgic 14.1.1.0 as the server where I deploy my Ear file and the version of java I working with is 11.0.8. My question is very simple yet did not found any solution for it.

The build, deployment and even the weblogic startup works properly only once and then take so long(30 minutes for each). If I want it to get back fast I have to reboot the computer then I will have only one shot(build,weblogic startup and deploy) then it will go back to be very slow.

At this point I am not able to work on any task and I really could not found any solution for this issue.

Any advice could help, thanks.

I tried to update the java.security file but it did not sole the issue.

Comment: You can take several thread dumps during startup when if takes a long time.